# Why List return empty when execute 2nd event

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Why List return empty when execute 2nd event?

```
List<string> ErrorList = new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

protected void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
          ErrorList.Add(i);      
       }
   txtResult.Text = "Length of list: " + ErrorList.Count; 
 }

protected void btnSecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtResult.Text = "Length of list: " + ErrorList.Count; 
 }
```

> When click btnFirst: txtResult.Text = "Length of list: 5"
>
> When click btnSecond: txtResult.Text = "Length of list: 0"

Comment: You should study and understand [ASP.NET Page LifeCycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: Because the page - and all it's variables - are newly created for each request.

Comment: as explained in above comments, new variable will be created on each request. hence you can choose option to store errorlist in Session so it will be persisted through out user session

Comment: And just a side note, don't assign `int` values to an `array` or `IEnumerable` of `string` in any language. Even if the language lets you get away with it, anyone who inherits your code will be cursing your name if they have to debug anything.  `ErrorList.Add(i.ToString())` to prevent programmer-on-programmer violence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code but it only work if cookies enabled on client side
The session is a container located server side. In the cookie on client (browser) is a id to make a relation with the session. It is also possible to save more informations in a cookie but i would not recommend it. All other informations infos are lost every request.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

protected void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<string> ErrorList = new List<string>();

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
        ErrorList.Add(i);      
   }
   Session["Errors"] = ErrorList;
   txtResult.Text = "Length of list: " + ErrorList.Count;
 }

protected void btnSecond_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<string> ErrorList = (List<string>)Session["Errors"];
   txtResult.Text = "Length of list: " + ErrorList.Count; 
}
```

Comment: Hope your users don't press btnSecond before btnFirst

Comment: @Steve btnSecond is visible after users click btnFirst. :)

Comment: Have any way to save List values ?